# Word to express without a negative connotation that a measure has no effect at all

Tags: single-word-requests

The words meaningless, pointless, useless all have some degree of negative connotation to me as a non-native english speaker.

I'm trying to express that a certain configuration has no effect to a system at all. The sentence I am trying to use is: The configuration xyz is ... (without any effect).

*Update: The negative connotation that I mean is what may be communicated inadvertently to the one that attempted to effect the system when he is told by the other that his configuration has no effect. I altered the title of the question to express where the negative connotation I meant referred to*

Comment: configuration xyz doesn't work or isn't working.

Comment: I'm looking for one word.

Comment: The best one I can think of is ineffective but that still has a negative connotation.

Comment: As a programmer, I think of _void_

Comment: Null, as in "The configuration xyz turned out to be null (or a null configuration or hypothesis)." Null, however, has a negative connotation, albeit not terribly obvious. It does mean, in part,  "of no consequence, effect, or value; insignificant." (Free Dictionary).

Comment: Inconsequential might work.

Comment: The system's effect is *neutral* to the end result.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a term borrowed from other science, such as *[inert](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=inert)*

> 2. Chemistry Not readily reactive with other elements; forming few or no chemical compounds.
> 3. Having no pharmacologic, metabolic, or other physiological effect.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

or *[unreactive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unreactive)* (sometimes *nonreactive*)

> Having little tendency to react chemically.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

These terms are more often used in chemistry or biology, but may be found in physics (describing response to magnetic or electrical fields).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just simply say "The configuration xyz has no effect"?

Comment: I feel like accepting this answer since none of the proposed single words seem fit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **benign**.

In quite a few contexts, mainly medical, it has a positive connotation.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benign) defines it as:

> adj.
>
> 1. a. Having little or no detrimental effect; harmless: a benign chemical; benign indifference.
>    b. Of no danger to health; not malignant or disease-causing: a benign tumor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But something benign has effect right? A harmless effect. A benign tumor alters a person's physiology (without causing harm). I'm looking for a word that implies having absolutely no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

- ***Irrelevant*** may have a slightly negative connotation.
- ***Negligible*** means very small. 
  I suppose something could have a measurable effect that's small enough
  that you are willing/able to ignore it;
  that would be considered *negligible*,
  so this might not be the right word for you. 
  (This is comparable to ***null***, which somebody else mentioned.)
- ***Non-applicable*** strikes me as neutral.
- ***Neutral*** may be useful. 
  I'm not sure how useful it is as a standalone word,
  but it can be used as part of a hyphenated word. 
  For example, when somebody proposes a change in the income tax structure
  (e.g., from graduated to a flat tax) that keeps the  average rate the same,
  so the government collects the same amount of money
  (but with a different distribution of who pays how much),
  the proposal is called ***revenue-neutral***. 
  Since you haven't really identified your context ("system" is pretty general),
  I can't tell how well this will work for you.

Comment: I like inapplicable too

Answer (score 0):

If the important thing is that your configuration does not have any negative effect, then **nondetrimental** may be appropriate.

> Not detrimental; harmless. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nondetrimental))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion too. Non detrimental implies having some effect. One that isn't harmful. I'm looking for a word that implies having absolutely no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the configuration of XYZ is ***[inconsequential](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inconsequential)***:

> of little or no importance; insignificant; trivial.

[TFD]